# Reescribiendo una consulta en mysql

Tags: mysql

Abra otra forma de realizar esta consulta, quiero ver si se puede contar los distintos registros TarjetaID, agrupandolos por el DoctorID

```
SELECT 
YEAR(V.VentaFecha) ANO,
MONTH(V.VentaFecha) MES,
CONCAT(IFNULL(D.DoctorNombre,'Sin Medico'),' ',IFNULL(D.DoctorApellido,' ')) DOCTOR,
COUNT(DISTINCT(V.TarjetaID)) CANTIDAD_PACIENTES,
sum((V.VentaTotal)) MONTO
FROM venta V
left  JOIN paciente P ON P.TarjetaID = V.TarjetaID
left  JOIN farmacias_zonificacion FZ ON FZ.CD_CLIENTE = V.FarmaciaID  
left  JOIN doctor D ON D.DoctorID = P.MedicoTratante
WHERE V.VentaFecha BETWEEN finicial AND ffinal
GROUP by  MONTH(V.VentaFecha),DOCTOR
ORDER BY  MONTH(V.VentaFecha),DOCTOR ASC
```

y es que no esta contando bien la cantidad de pacientes, osea se esta saltando algunos, en esta otra estoy agrupando por Farmacia y medico y si me da bien el resultado

```
SELECT 
YEAR(V.VentaFecha) ANO,
MONTH(V.VentaFecha) MES,
IFNULL(FZ.CD_CLIENTE,'sin codigo') CODIGO,
IFNULL(FZ.CLIENTE,'Sin farmacia ') FARMACIA,,
COUNT(DISTINCT(V.TarjetaID)) CANTIDAD_PACIENTES,
sum(DISTINCT (V.VentaTotal)) MONTO
FROM venta V
inner  JOIN paciente P ON P.TarjetaID = V.TarjetaID
inner  JOIN farmacias_zonificacion FZ ON FZ.CD_CLIENTE = V.FarmaciaID  
WHERE V.VentaFecha BETWEEN finicial AND ffinal
GROUP by  MONTH(V.VentaFecha),FZ.CLIENTE
ORDER BY  MONTH(V.VentaFecha),FZ.CLIENTE ASC
```

[image: tabla de ventas]

Como puedo plantear la segunda consulta, quiero contar por farmacia la cantidad de tarjetas agrupadas por mes ya que dentro de un mes se puede repetir los pacientes

Comment: Tienes datos de prueba y una descripción de las tablas para poder probar esas consultas? Por favor, edita la pregunta y añádelos. Toda consulta es válida dependiendo de lo que uno necesite ;)

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!